# How do I make it obvious which Firefox Profile is being used?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

There are [security advantages](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106940/does-using-creating-a-seprate-firefox-profile-cause-a-seprate-security-context-t) to opening potentially sensitive sites in a separate Firefox profile from a normal one.

Is there any way of clearly indicating to a user which Firefox windows are using a particular Firefox Profile?

Comment: I would just write an add-on to display the required information.

Comment: @Ramhound That'd be in Javascript right?

Comment: [Show Profile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-profile/)

Comment: Does anybody have anything that will...I dunno put a border around the inside or of the window, or change the color of the task bar?

Comment: You can install a theme in one of the profiles to make it obvious which is which, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/

Comment: @Curtis good point I forgot about those.

Comment: @Curtis I know this is a lame question, but seriously you can answer it, and I'll select your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a theme in one of the profiles to make it obvious which is which, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/